A short fiction about two people who became super intelligent thanks to an experimental drug and fight to death just in their minds
I read this short fiction (not very short, probably novelette, maybe even short novella, rather than short story) about 20 years ago. In was in a collection, not sure it was in English, possibly in French translation. It definitely does not sound like a French original SF.
I don't remember much. The POV character had his brain damaged (maybe he almost drowned). So they try an experiemental drug on him to repair the damage. But they give him too much and he becomes super-intelligent. So much so that he wants more and more intelligence. He manages to steal more of this drug and flees from the hospital (or experimental medical facility) where he was first treated. The authorities try to catch him but he is much too clever for them, especially after taking the stolen doses of the drug.
At some point he realises that there is another super intelligent person. He tracks him and they are both convinced that only one such can survive, Earth is too small for two like them. So they engage in a titanic battle of minds.
But the other one has known of the existence of the POV first, has found him and had managed to imprint some kind of virus in his eidetic memory (IIRC, just by passing along him wearing a tee-shirt with a bizarre image on it). At some point of the mind battle the virus is activated and the POV loses, and dies.

Understand (1991) by Ted Chiang.

The story follows a man who is given an experimental drug to heal brain damage caused by anoxia after he nearly drowns. The drug regenerates his damaged neurons and has the unintended side effect of exponentially improving his intellect and motor skills. As he gets smarter and smarter, he is pursued by several government agencies. Eventually he receives a message from another super-intelligent test subject and enters into conflict with him.

The virus was indeed transferred from a shirt. At the end of the story we read:

An image of the grocery store when Reynolds passed by. The psychedelic shirt the boy was wearing; Reynolds had programmed the display to implant a suggestion within me, ensuring that my "randomly" reprogrammed psyche remained receptive.


IIRC, there were bits and pieces of the suggestion/programming scattered throughout the main character's path to meet the adversary. That way the main character couldn't recognize that they were being programmed.

Coincidentally, the Wikipedia page mentions a TV show in the works as of June 2024.

I have read this story.  I have it here somewhere.  The conflict wasn't "there can be only one."  The conflict was that the main character is actually the bad guy.  He is acting to improve his condition so that he can take over.  The other guy is staying in the background, trying to improve things for everyone.  The "good guy" kills the "bad guy."  Hmmm.  Which was the good guy and which was the bad guy?  Kind of (intentionally) morally ambiguous.
